# How to install ImageMagick on Joyent Node SmartMachine?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I'd like to use ImageMagick on a Joyent Node SmartMachine.
I tried

```
pkgin in ImageMagick-6.6.1.5nb1
```

and get a bunch of "X11 not found" errors

```
calculating dependencies for ImageMagick-6.6.1.5nb1...
/usr/lib/libX11.so, needed by ImageMagick-6.6.1.5nb1 is not present in this system.
/usr/X11/lib/libXss.so.1, needed by ImageMagick-6.6.1.5nb1 is not present in this system.
```

I also tried downloading the solaris package as explained on [ImageMagick site](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).
Has anyone had success with it or found another way to use ImageMagick or other comparable graphics library with Node.js on a Joyent Node SmartMachine (for use with Node.js)

Any ideas?

Comment: seems to work after upgrading to the newest version of pkgsrc (http://pkgsrc.joyent.com/sdc/2010Q4/gcc45) as described here [Upgrading to Pkgsrc 2010Q4](http://wiki.joyent.com/display/node/Upgrading+to+Pkgsrc+2010Q4)